# How to search complex queries in react material ui table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is one student table consists of id, name, marks, attendance, fees.
Now I want to search student from the table on the basis of complex queries like a student with marks less than 50 or attendance greater than 75. How can I code this in Javascript and ReactJs?

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript / ReactJS skills ?

Comment: I am a beginner. I have done the string searching part. but I am not getting a proper answer for the <75 kinda query.

Comment: Please provide your actual code that display that table. You should provide what you have done so far and what you tried. If you don't know how to do it at all, you can at least provide your actual code so we can explain where to start.